# Optimization problem involving matrix as a decision variable

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations

> Given matrices $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $M,N\in\mathbb{R}^{v\times v}$. Find a nonzero matrix $P\in\mathbb{R}^{v\times n}$, where $v \leq n$, such that
>
> $$\min_{P} \| PA - MP \| + \| P^T N P - B \|.$$

Can you please suggest me algorithms/methods to solve such a problem? What class of optimization problems does this problem belong to?

Comment: Which matrix norm?

Comment: What exactly does "nonzero matrix" mean?  Not the matrix of all zeros? Well, how about a matrix with all elements equal to 10^(-16)?

Comment: Let's say the matrix norm is $L_2$. Non-zero matrix means at least one entry in the matrix is nonzero.